# Did the Jedi highly regulate cortosis like kyber?

Tags: star-wars

In the new canon, was cortosis heavily controlled by the Jedi, like it was in Legends? I've only seen it mentioned once in canon, and the mine where it was found was immediately destroyed.   Was this the only source in canon, or was there more and it was kept hidden by the Jedi?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cortosis

Comment: I saw that, but I thought that perhaps the archives were incomplete.

Comment: If the item does not appear in their records, it does not exist.